# Can't turn off Chrome autocomplete using Angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, autocomplete, angular-formly

I found [here](https://gitter.im/formly-js/angular-formly?at=56378d3b63efc9f855ec8e36) that I cant turn off Chrome autocomplete. I do everything what I have to do, but Chrome's autocomplete still work. Can't understand where is my mistake and what I have to do to fix that.
My form field:

```
const field_password = {
        key: 'password',
        type: 'input',
        wrapper: 'page-form-field',
        templateOptions: {
          placeholder: 'sigin.password.label',
          type: 'password',
          required: true,
          focus: $ctrl.isPasswordRecover,
        },
      };

  $ctrl.fields = [
    // ...,
    field_password
  ];
```

My option for the form

```
  $ctrl.options = {
    removeChromeAutoComplete: true
  };
```

My form:

```
        formly-form(
          form   = '$ctrl.form',
          model  = '$ctrl.model',
          fields = '$ctrl.fields',
          options = '$ctrl.options'
        )
```

And my formly config:

```
ction() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('WebClientApp.formly', [])

    // Formly
    .config(function(formlyConfigProvider) {
    //...

    })
    .run(function(formlyConfig, formlyValidationMessages) {
      formlyConfig.extras.removeChromeAutoComplete = true;
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
templateOptions: {
  label: 'COUNTRY',
  placeholder: 'Country',
  attributes: {
    autocomplete: 'off'
  },
  required: true,
}
```

Comment: I upvote that - as it worked for me in configuring autocomplete fields like login and password fields to receive the correct autocomplete values... but somehow it didn't work for turning off all instances of autocomplete... not quite sure why this is...

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML set the autocomplete attribute to "off".  the method that is mentioned in formly no longer works apparently, or at least didn't when I tried it.